# Change brush strokes of drawn image

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm really new to Illustrator and I drew an image I like, but then I noticed there were different brushes and think it'd look cooler with another one, so is there any way to change the brush strokes for what I've already drawn without having to trace over the entire thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select your stroke with the black
  arrow.
- Open the Brushes palette.
- Click on the new brush you want.
- Tada!

Comment: One of the major advantages of vector graphics is that you can select the lines to move them around or change the color or any other edits.

Comment: Yes! And the best part is that you can even change the settings of the brush you used and all instances that used that brush get updated with the changes even if they are not selected. That way you can account for scaling or other eventualities. Making a drawing with stronger strokes is a breeze that way.